# self.table_name is not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, migration

I am trying to learn rails Active Record.
Learnt that `self.table_name` can be used to rename a table which rails create default.

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
    self.table_name = "ordered"
end
```

But when I run the migration first time , I still get the `orders` table, not the one which I mentioned in the string. What is the mistake done here?

migration:

```
class CreateOrders < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :orders do |t|

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: What is the migration that you ran?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class CreateOrders < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :ordered do |t|
      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

This will create an `ordered` table.

If you've already got your `orders` table, you can use the following:

```
$ rails g migration ChangeOrdersToOrdered

#db/migrate/change_orders_to_ordered_______.rb
class ChangeOrdersToOrdered < ActiveRecord::Migration
   rename_name :orders, :ordered
end

$ rake db:migrate
```

---

**Tables != Classes**

You have to remember that your *migrations* are not the same as your *classes* - they are mutually exclusive.

Although the naming conventions are similar, and Rails does a great job of linking the two, the fact remains that you can call your tables whatever you want -- it will have no bearing on your models *unless* you specifically designate the table tied to the model.

Setting `self.table_name` only sets the class that model will *read* (it's a [class method](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/ModelSchema/ClassMethods/table_name)):

> Guesses the table name (in forced lower-case) based on the name of the class in the inheritance hierarchy descending directly from ActiveRecord::Base. So if the hierarchy looks like: `Reply < Message < ActiveRecord::Base`, then `Message` is used to guess the table name even when called on Reply. The rules used to do the guess are handled by the Inflector class in `Active Support`, which knows almost all common English inflections. You can add new inflections in `config/initializers/inflections.rb`.

This means that no matter what you refer to in your `self.table_name`, you are open to use whichever migrations you want.

Answer (score 0):

As an addition to @richard-peck 's comment, the correct syntax for renaming a table from a migration is:
`rename_table`